# sonarqube only latest commit should be scan

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, devops

We recently integrated sonarqube to our existing build and release environment.
Everytime any commit triggers sonar scanning total project again instead of latest commit.

How to make sonar to scan only the latest commits from second time onwards as it is taking lot of time for scanning.

if not let us know any alternative for the same.

Ps:- I am editing the previous question as i am not able to ask new question. Parden me for that.

Comment: Did you try another port and/or check if that port is in use?

Comment: Great!  Feel free to add that as an answer here as well.  Answering your own questions is acceptable in Stack Overflow in general (am unaware of any specific rules against it in this specific forum).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use preview or incermental option while scanning the project,incremental will be good option to run scan on delta changes.
https://docs.sonarqube.org/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=6947686#content/view/6947686

Comment: Thank you for reply. But in sonar version 6.7.5 incremental option was not working they have been depricated.

Comment: If you are using gerrit validation,you can use preview mode ,in this case only delta comparison happened and sents the voilation to gerrit server.it will not update the sonarcube server project. Once the code is merged,you can trigger the sonar validation on whole project.